# How to calculate the thickness of the residual stress layer generated by a machining process

Tags: mechanical-engineering, stresses, machining

Machining a metal part will create residual stresses on its surface due to the deformation that the process introduces to it, is there any model to estimate how thick will this stress layer may be?

Comment: If you cut the surface, you actually cut through the grains, this kind of plastic deformation actually makes the metal stronger, (no residual stresses). if you forge it, then yes it creates residual stresses in the metals, so what kind of machining we are talking about ? and what type of materials ? cristalline ? amorf ?

Comment: @SamFarjamirad Cutting through the grains will produce stress in the material, there's no doubt about it. And, yes, the material hardens as you point out, that is one indication that you got stresses. Cold forging will also generate residual stresses, but they will be distributed throughout the solid. I'm looking for a general model which maybe takes into account the hardness of the material, or the grain size, etc. But if a general model does not exist, something for steel would be ok.

Comment: Although I don't own it, Davim's [*Surface Integrity in Machining*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-84882-874-2) appears to address this topic and may be useful.

Comment: Probably covered by Timoshenko...

Comment: Not an answer,but, 25 years ago steel research labs( Valourec, Nippon, Sumitomo, etc.) could not calculate it for high strength steels ,eg. 90.000 psi yield. The object was to prepare test coupons with no cold work or residual stress.

Comment: I would assume there is no such model as there are too many factors to create a generalized model. For example, forgetting about what the material is, the way the material was produced alone, ie, hot rolled/cold rolled/cast/forged/extruded/etc, will have a big impact on the residual stresses and how well or poorly it absorbs added stresses. Probably the most prominent reason being that residual stress and those induced by manufacturing processes don't form a definite "layer" but more of a gradient from the surface inward.

Comment: You dont need to include all those variables in such model, you can start simple: assume that the material is is a free-stress state and that the only source of stress is the machining operation. Or you can have any initial stress condition you want. Since machining works are surface operations, you will have a very clear stress concentration at the surface, you can call it a layer. The reference that Chemomechanics cited gives examples of these layers being aprox. 0.2mm thick.